# Salesforce Sandbox - unable to execute test methods successfully

Tags: salesforce, force.com, apex

I have a sandbox that simply refuses to run test code.

I wrote some simple apex in a trial org, and after it was activated (purchased) the code became inactive. Thus, I span up a sandbox and finished things off, writing some simple test coverage to allow me to deploy the class and trigger to production. I have made sure in the sandbox that the class and trigger were restored to 'active' status.

Issue is - I try to run test coverage, it instantly tells me the request is queued, but that 0/0 Test Methods have passed. The status of the queued request remains at 'Selected Job is not yet complete' forever more. The more I try to run the test class, the more Im cheerily told 'Selected Job is not yet complete', and it never completes.

Has anyone seen this, or heard of possible solution?..  Any suggestions most appreciated!

Comment: Can you try from the Eclipse IDE? Maybe also hit "clear code coverage" and "compile all classes"... But sounds like a case for support

Comment: Cheers for suggestions. Did all you proposed and no better. Will log case... thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets just let this one die a quiet death...

Comment: What was the solution here?  I am having the same issue this morning!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug - did you try creating another test class to see if that would work?